# Spyder :Error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, anaconda, kernel, spyder

An error occurred while starting the kernel in Spyder

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
kernel_name=self.kernel_name
File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "G:\Anaconda\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel‑bd9c021b8392.json'
```

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this problem please open the Anaconda Prompt and run there

```
conda update --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn of fire wall and Run spyder as an administrator.